# Pyqt crashes when trying to show opencv videostream

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5, qthread

I tried code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404713) answer and it crashes with error `Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)` after some time (2-10 sec.) and sometimes with `0xC0000005`. It crashes immediately if I try to drag the window.
However when I put `time.sleep(0.1)` in `run` it works fine. If I use sleeps shorter than 0.1 it crashes again.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt
import cv2
import sys
import time

class CamThread(QThread):
    changemap = pyqtSignal('QImage')

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

        while True:
            ret, img_rgb = cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.convert = QImage(self.rgb.data, self.rgb.shape[1], self.rgb.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.p = self.convert.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changemap.emit(self.p)
                #time.sleep(0.1)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'webcam'

        self.initUI()

    @pyqtSlot('QImage')
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(640, 480)
        thr = CamThread(self)
        thr.changemap.connect(self.setImage)
        thr.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = App()
#win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
win.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())
```

I thought that the problem is somewhere in signals/slots but haven't been able to find anything relevant.

- Windows 10
- Python - 3.7
- Pyqt - 5.12
- OpenCV - 3.4.5.20

Comment: change `self.rgb` to `rgb`, `self.convert` to `convert` and `self.p` to `p`

Comment: Tried. Changes nothing

Comment: execute it in the CMD, there you should surely give you more information

Comment: Still crushes. Shows nothing in CMD not even previous error.

Comment: mmm, why do you want an image beyond 100ms ?, a camera provides a 30FPS image that is 30 ms, what is the FPS of your camera?

Comment: I don't actually. Just want to know what the problem is in case i meet it later. It takes ~ 0.01 sec. for a frame if I only use OpenCV even with blur and some other processing. And 10 fps camera is not the best what one could want from CV application, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using `QMutex` and `QWaitCondition` to prevent update call while main thread is already updating. Apparently, issue was in that. [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc), I'm new here as you see, should I make an answer in original thread?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QMutex, QWaitCondition
import cv2
import sys
import time


class CamThread(QThread):
    changemap = pyqtSignal('QImage')

    def __init__(self, mutex, condition):
        super().__init__()
        self.mutex = mutex
        self.condition = condition

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
        while True:
            try:
                ret, img_rgb = cap.read()
                if ret:
                    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                    #any other image processing here

                    convert = QImage(rgb.data, rgb.shape[1], rgb.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                    p = convert.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                    self.changemap.emit(p)
                    self.condition.wait(self.mutex)

            except:
                print('error')


class App(QWidget):
    time = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'webcam'
        self.mutex = QMutex()
        self.condition = QWaitCondition()
        self.initUI()

    @pyqtSlot('QImage')
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.mutex.lock()
        try:
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        finally:
            self.mutex.unlock()
            self.condition.wakeAll()

    def initUI(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(640, 480)
        self.thr = CamThread(mutex = self.mutex,condition=self.condition)
        self.thr.changemap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.thr.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = App()
win.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())
```

N.B. You still need to properly stop thread and close camera connection in this example.