# What is the difference between an opencv BGR image and its reverse version RGB image[:,:,::-1]?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, qimage

I'm trying to show an opencv image with a QLabel. I got two different versions of the image, first one is the opencv BGR image, the second one is the RGB image using image[:,:,::-1], the BGR version works fine but the RGB version doesn't work.

**The following code works fine**

```
src = cv.imread('image.jpg')
h,w,ch = src.shape
bytesPerLine = ch * w
qImg = QImage(src.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
qImg = qImg.rgbSwapped()
self.ui.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
```

**These code doesn't work :**

```
src = cv.imread('image.jpg')
src = src[:,:,::-1]
h,w,ch = src.shape
bytesPerLine = ch * w
qImg = QImage(src.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
self.ui.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have noticed opencv reads the image in BGR format but QImage in RGB, in your first method you convert to QImage without doing the conversion and then you use `rgbSwapped()` method to do the conversion.

By testing the first method I get:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 291 usec per loop
```

---

In the second method you try to do it before converting it to QImage but when I execute it I get the following error presuming that you also get it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx.py", line 18, in <module>
    qImg = QtGui.QImage(src.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QImage(): too many arguments
  QImage(QSize, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(bytes, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(bytes, int, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(List[str]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(str, format: str = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(QImage): argument 1 has unexpected type 'memoryview'
  QImage(Any): too many arguments
```

And this is because numpy uses memoryview to optimize certain tasks. And in this case when doing `src[:,:,::-1]` one way to optimize is not to modify the data but the way to access the data, this is done through the [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects).

And in this case QImage does not support this type of data, so the solution is to access the bytes using the [`tobytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.tobytes) or `bytes()`:

```
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    src = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    src = src[:,:,::-1]
    h, w, ch = src.shape
    bytesPerLine = ch * w
    qImg = QtGui.QImage(src.data.tobytes(), w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    # Or
    # qImg = QtGui.QImage(bytes(src.data), w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    w.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Time:

```
500 loops, best of 5: 523 usec per loop
```

---

Another solution is to use the `cvtColor()` function of opencv that if you modify the data:

```
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    src = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    src = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w, ch = src.shape
    bytesPerLine = ch * w
    qImg = QtGui.QImage(src.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    w.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Time:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 263 usec per loop
```

Comment: Nice work, sir. I suspect the `cvtColor()` will be the fastest as OpenCV doubtless will do it with SIMD.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It seems that you are right, using timeit I have made the measurements observing that the cvtColor method of opencv is the best

Comment: Thank you for adding the timing checks to what was already a good answer. I'd vote it up again if I could :-)

Comment: It's really helpful, Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @eyllanesc QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888 Works by why not QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB444 can you provide reason?

Comment: @Nixel The cameras usually use RGB where for 8-bit interlaced channels, then you should use a QImage that supports that format, in this case Format_RGB888, Format_RGB444 is not an appropriate format because it is clearly waiting for 4bits per channel. I recommend you check the docs of how an image is placed in memory.