# I am trying to display video stream from opencv to pyqt5 interface but my code is not working

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I am trying to display video stream from opencv to pyqt5 interface. I adapted the code from the answer to one question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404349/pyqt-showing-video-stream-from-opencv#:~:text=The%20problem%20is,label.%20For%20example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404349/pyqt-showing-video-stream-from-opencv#:%7E:text=The%20problem%20is,label.%20For%20example) %3A. But when I run my code in pycharm, I get this error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Gests_Recognition(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Gests_Recognition, self).__init__()
        self.running = True

    change_pixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    gest_map = {
        0: "up",
        1: "down",
        2: "right",
        3: "left",
        4: "forward",
        5: "back"
    }

    columns = ['x11', 'x21', 'x12', 'x22', 'x13', 'x23', 'x14', 'x24', 'x15', 'x25',
               'x16', 'x26', 'x17', 'x27', 'x18', 'x28', 'x19', 'x29', 'x110', 'x210', 'x111',
               'x211', 'x112', 'x212', 'x113', 'x213', '114', '214', '115', 'x215', 'x116',
               'x216', 'x117', 'x217', 'x118', 'x218', 'x119', 'x219', 'x120', 'x220', 'x121',
               'x221']

    def mapper(self, val):
        return Gests_Recognition.gest_map[val]

    def run(self):
        model = load_model("gestures_model.h5", compile=False)
        drawingModule = mediapipe.solutions.drawing_utils
        handsModule = mediapipe.solutions.hands

        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        with handsModule.Hands(static_image_mode=False, min_detection_confidence=0.7, min_tracking_confidence=0.7,
                               max_num_hands=1) as hands:
            while self.running:
                # frame == 480 640
                ret, frame = capture.read()
                if ret:
                    processed_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    height_frame, width_frame, channels_frame = frame.shape
                    bytes_line = channels_frame * width_frame
                    qt_frame = QImage(processed_frame.data, width_frame, height_frame, bytes_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                    qt_frame = qt_frame.scaled(640, 480, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

                    self.change_pixmap.emit(qt_frame)

                    results = hands.process(processed_frame)

                    cv2.imshow('Hands recognizer', frame)
                    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

                    # do something else.

            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            capture.release()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def set_image(self, image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.cam_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cam_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 60, 160, 150))
        self.cam_btn.setObjectName("cam_btn")
        self.cam_btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.cam_btn.clicked.connect(self.gest_recognition)
        self.cam_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: #aae053;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/hand.png');\n"
                                        "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n"
                                        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #81eb3b;}")

        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.move(40, 240)
        self.label.resize(640, 480)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border: 5px solid black;")

    def gest_recognition(self):
        if self.cam_btn.isChecked():
            self.cam_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: red;\n"
                                       "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/pause.png');\n"
                                       "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n")
            self.thread_gests = QtCore.QThread()
            self.g_recog = Gests_Recognition()

            self.g_recog.moveToThread(self.thread_gests)
            self.g_recog.change_pixmap.connect(self.set_image)
            self.thread_gests.start()
        else:
            self.cam_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: #aae053;\n"
                                       "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/hand.png');\n"
                                       "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n"
                                       "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #81eb3b;}")
            self.g_recog.running = False
            self.thread_gests.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this concept
create a python file  main_window.py
Paste this in it

```
import sys

# import some PyQt5 modules
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

# import Opencv module
import cv2

from ui_main_window import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # call QWidget constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # create a timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        # set timer timeout callback function
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.viewCam)
        # set control_bt callback clicked  function
        self.ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)

    # view camera
    def viewCam(self):
        # read image in BGR format
        ret, image = self.cap.read()
        # convert image to RGB format
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # get image infos
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        # create QImage from image
        qImg = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        # show image in img_label
        self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))

    # start/stop timer
    def controlTimer(self):
        # if timer is stopped
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            # create video capture
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            # start timer
            self.timer.start(20)
            # update control_bt text
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("Stop")
        # if timer is started
        else:
            # stop timer
            self.timer.stop()
            # release video capture
            self.cap.release()
            # update control_bt text
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("Start")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # create and show mainWindow
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Create a new file and name as ui_main_window.py and paste code below

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(525, 386)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.control_bt.setObjectName("control_bt")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Cam view"))
        self.image_label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.control_bt.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
```